# Content Expiration - IIS 6

Tags: iis, content-expiration

If I set the content expiration for static files to something like 14 days and I decide to update some files later on, will IIS know to serve the updated files or will the client have to wait until the expiration date?

Or is it the other way around where the browser requests a new file if the modified date is different?

Sometimes I update a file on the server and I have to do a hard refresh (CTRL+F5) to see the difference.  Currently I have it to expire after 1 day.

Answer (score 2):

The web browser, and any intermediate proxies, are allowed to cache the page until its expiration date. This means that IIS might not even be aware of the client viewing the page.

Answer (score 0):

You want [ETags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag)

> An ETag is an opaque identifier assigned by a web server to a specific version of a resource found at a URL. If the resource content at that URL ever changes, a new and different ETag is assigned. Used in this manner ETags are similar to fingerprints, and they can be quickly compared to determine if two versions of a resource are the same or not. [...]

Comment: Is there something I need to do in order to get IIS to generate ETags?